# Rollback seed data inserts after Test case

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I am developing a JPA application with Kotlin and Ktor and am using Hibernate as ORM.

My test database is h2 and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to create so that after SessionFactory close all data is cleaned up.

However now to have a clean database state I would need to recreate EntityManagerFactory after each TestCase which makes the Tests very very slow, therefore I am looking for a different way to do this.

I have read about Transactional Annotation but apparently that will only work inside Spring Framework.

Does anybody have an idea how to rollback inserts coming from a before method after a test case has run?

Here is an example:

```
class ChampionDaoTests {
    var chmpDao : IChampionDao? = null

    val chmp1 = TestHelper.generateChampionObj()
    val chmp2 = TestHelper.generateChampionObj()

    @Before
    fun before() {
        // Should be rolled back after each Test case
        chmpDao = ChampionDao(TestHelper.getEntityManager())
        (this.chmpDao as ChampionDao).saveChampion(chmp1)
        (this.chmpDao as ChampionDao).saveChampion(chmp2)
    }

    @Test
    fun testFindAllMethod() {
        val chmps : List<Champion> = this.chmpDao!!.findAllChampions()
        assertTrue { chmps.size == 2 }
    }

    @Test
    fun testFindChampionMethod() {
        val chmp = this.chmpDao!!.findChampionById(chmp1.chmpid!!)
        assertNotNull(chmp)
        if (chmp != null) {
            assertTrue { chmp.equals(chmp1) }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testFindChampionMethodWrongParam() {
        val chmp = this.chmpDao!!.findChampionById(-1)
        assertNull(chmp)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the transaction handling by calling EntityManager.getTransaction().begin() and then in an After method calling rollback on the transaction?

Comment: Hm but I would have to commit the transaction to have the entities inserted right? Can I rollback already commited transactions? Also can I rollback multiple transactions?

Comment: No you don't just call EntityManger.flush() that will execute the SQL statements.

Comment: ok got it, so I will just have to start a transaction at the begin of my before method, and roll it back in the after method. Thanks will try that out.

Comment: I added an idea of a base test in the answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a base test class with a before and after method that controls the transaction for every test method:

```
public abstract class BaseTestWithEntityManager {

    protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    protected static EntityManager em;
    protected EntityTransaction transaction;

    @Before
    public void beforeSuper() {
        transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
    }

    @After
    public void afterSuper() {
        em.flush();
        if (transaction.isActive()) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("store");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {
        if (em.isOpen()) {
            em.close();
        }
        if (emf.isOpen()) {
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```